# regex in textfield

Tags: javascript, regex

dear all..i have this code:

```
<script>
var str="KD-R435MUN2D";
var matches=str.match(/(EE|[EJU]).*(D)/i);
if (matches) {
     var firstletter = matches [1];
     var secondletter = matches [2];
     var thirdletter = matches [3];
alert(firstletter + secondletter + thirdletter);
}else{
      alert (":(");
}
</script>
```

i want it can control a textfield `<input type="text" id="mod">`..how must i do?

Comment: the question seems awfully familiar.. isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: i'm just continue my project and make a question step by step bcoz at last time several people not understand with my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

HTML:

```
<input id="mod" onchange="checkRegexp" />
```

JS:

```
function checkRegexp()
      {
      d = document.getElementById("mod");

      val = d.value;

      // Do the regexp on value
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add event listener to textfield and call the function when the event is fired.
You can get text using `document.getElementById('mod').value`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mod").val();
var matches=str.match(/(EE|[EJU]).*(D)/i);
if (matches) {
     var firstletter = matches [1];
     var secondletter = matches [2];
     var thirdletter = matches [3];
alert(firstletter + secondletter + thirdletter);
}else{
      alert (":(");
}
</script>
```